# Strip file paths from errors sent to sentry

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sentry

I'm setting up a self hosted Sentry for a CRA project I'm working on.

I'm having trouble getting sentry to understand where my artefacts are located (js and source maps). Uploading the javascript and source maps works as expected, and I can see them for each of my releases.

They are available at `~/main.XYZ.js` and `~/main.XYZ.js.map` respectively inside Sentry.

When my app at `https://www.website.com/path/to/file/` records an error it send it to Sentry successfully. But the error provides a path for the js file that crashed,  `~/path/to/file/main.XYZ.js`. When Sentry then tries to find the error, it looks at `~/path/to/file/main.XYZ.js` instead of `~/main.XYZ.js` (where it actually is).

Is there any way to strip the path and just having Sentry looking at root directly?

Note: I was successful when setting the url prefix to `~/path/to/file`. However that approach won't work in the real world later for me since that path is subject to change depending on what stage in development I'm in.